# Why elements on screen are not fullscreen?

Tags: html, css, jsx, fullscreen

I don't have my web-app on react full-screen, having so small amount of elements on the page.
[image]
[image]
[image]
Css:

```
html {
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display:block;
  position: fixed;
  object-fit: cover;  
  z-index: -2;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("./assets/background-img.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-position-y: -24em;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Also have some other styles for h-s, etc, but I suppose it's not the cause of the problem, so I removed is.
JSX:

```
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className='header-div'>
        <h3 className='text-above'>
          -------   A HIKING GUIDE
        </h3>
        <div className='main-text'>
          Be Prepared For The Mountains And Beyond!
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Everything i tried is in the code, and i can't figure it out. Hope on your help

Comment: Are you asking why `.header-div` doesn't fill the body element vertically? How would be be able to tell when you haven't shown us the CSS for it? Please read [ask]. Provide a [mcve]. Reduce this problem to the CSS and HTML (i.e. show us the HTML the JSX genreates instead of the raw JSX). Use the stack snippets features of the question editor to provide a live demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your background positioning, I commented it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body,html {
        height: 100%; 
        width: 100%;
        display:block;
        position: fixed;
        object-fit: cover;  
        z-index: -2;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("./assets/background-img.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;
        /*background-position-y: -24em;*/
        background-size: 100% 100%;
                }
        * {
        margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```